# How do we authenticate a user in Flutter using Metamask(Mobile Application) pop up?

Tags: flutter, dart, blockchain, metamask

Is there any  way that  i can authenticate  a user in my dapp using  metamask (using  popup like in web ? )

Answer (score 0):

Read this chain it has some points to move you forward.
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/3735